# Regex for converting indented lines into code blocks

Tags: javascript, regex

I am simply making a Regex that parses for Code Blocks, problem is, there is a problem!

Now, basically my Code Blocks are like SO's, 4+ spaces or 1+ tab. Problem is, my regex is only grabbing the first and last lines of the code blocks :( I have no clue why.

Simply, this is my regex:

```
/^(?:( {4,}|\t+)(.+))$(?:(?:(?:\n?)( {4,}|\t+)(.+))*)$/
```

Then I am using it like this:

```
    .replace(/^(?:( {4,}|\t+)(.+))$(?:(?:(?:\n?)( {4,}|\t+)(.+))*)$/gmi, function (m, g1, g2, g3, g4) {
        return "<code>" + (g1 + g2) + ("\n" + g3 + g4) + "</code>";
    })
```

So my question is, how can I return all of the lines, and not just the first\last lines?

**BONUS** Is there a way I can remove the 4 spaces/1 tab before displaying it in a code block? :D

---

**EDIT**

I will show some example of what does not work:

Works:

```
    This is line #1, 4 spaces
    This is line #2, 4 spaces
```

Does not work:

```
    This is line #1, 4 spaces
    This is line #2, 4 spaces
    This is line #3, 4 spaces
```

What it does is it only will display lines #1 and #3.

---

**EDIT 2**

Just in-case you want the full context of my code, here it is:

```
    .replace(/^(?:( {4,}|\t+)(.+))$(?:(?:(?:\n?)( {4,}|\t+)(.+))*)$/gmi, function (m, g1, g2, g3, g4) {
        var marker = '(-{{ +_~ ' + codeblocks.length + ' ~_+ }}-)';
        !g3 ? codeblocks.push(g1 + g2) : codeblocks.push((g1 + g2) + ("\n" + g3 + g4));
        return marker;
    }) //Block

   //Other styling I don't want my code blocks affected by, that's why I hide them first

   .replace(/\(-\{\{ \+_~ ([0-9]*) ~_\+ \}\}-\)/g, function (m, g1) {
        return codeblocks[parseInt(g1, 10)] ? "<code>" + codeblocks[parseInt(g1, 10)] + "</code>" : m;
    }) //Block
```

Comment: The `^` char stands for the beginning of a line and `$` is the end of a line so your regular expression is told to only match a single line.

Comment: @Felix, I have two `$`, and it should be matching multiple lines. :)

Comment: Oh, nevermind, it's getting late :P

Comment: @Felix, I usually have to take a second look as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just using jQuery and some text areas to demonstrate proof of concept, so you may want to adjust use of newline chars used, but [Here's my take](http://jsfiddle.net/k8zvmjqc/1/):

```
<textarea id='code' cols='50' rows='10'></textarea>
<textarea id='codeblock' cols='50' rows='10'></textarea>
<script>
$('#code').on('keyup',function() {
  var code=$(this).val().replace(/(( {4}|\t)(.*?(\n|$)))+/g, function (m) {
    return "<code>" + m.replace(/(^|\n)( {4}|\t)/g,'$1') + "</code>";
  });
  $('#codeblock').val(code);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) Now, it seems to work, but to be honestly, I do not fully understand what you are doing. Is there a way to edit my current regex to make it work?

Comment: well i don't know what context you are using the `.replace` in, so I can't really tell you that.. but you should just be able to take the main `.replace` i have (including the callback) same as how you have posted. I assume. But like I said, I don't know what your actual context is.

Comment: Hmm ok, I will try to work with it, and I will let you know :) The code I gave was simplified, first I am actually hiding the code blocks, but then re-displaying them.

Comment: `.replace(/(( {4}|\t)(.*?\n))+/g, function (m) {
      return "<code>" + m.replace(/(^|\n)( {4}|\t)/g,'\n') + "</code>\n";
    });` this part is the equivalent of what you posted, but again, I don't know the context for which you are using the `.replace`

Comment: I took a better look at it, and soon after tested it. Yes, it seems to work very well :) One problem, and one question though. First, the problem, at the start of every code blocks there seems to be an extra trailing new line. Yet, it should start with the code. Next the question, I see in the code you do this: `(.*?\n)`. Now, wouldn't that mean there has to be a new line after the last line? What if there is no new line after my code block?

Comment: @MichaelJones  I have updated the code in my answer to better reflect what you're going for from your comment: the outer regex now looks for newline or end of string `(\n|$)` and the inner regex now replaces the spaces/tab with matched beginning of string or newline `$1` instead of just replacing with newline.  I did it the other way initially because as I mentioned in my post, I took some liberties for the sake of my PoC (basically I just wanted the code tags to be on their own lines to look cleaner) and that you'd likely want to adjust the newline stuff!

Comment: I've also [updated my PoC](http://jsfiddle.net/k8zvmjqc/1/) w/ the changes so you can see there is no longer a linebreak after opening or closing of code tag, accounting for end of string

Comment: Brilliant! :) I have implemented it, and it seems to be working perfectly now!!! Thank you so much, I have written so many regexs, but none are as working as well as this :D